# Linking from inlines to full add/change pages in django-admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, inline

I have an inline where I want to allow links to separate Add/Change pages for the child table, because the child table is way too big to be edited inline (dozens of fields).

I got the edit link working based on comment 13 here:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13163

But does anyone know how to change the function of the "Add another" button so that it will take me to the "Add" page, rather than just adding the new record in the inline?

Naturally, it would be nice if when we get to the "Add" page, the foreign key link to the parent table is already set to where it is getting added...

Thanks for any help...

Comment: I’d use some custom JavaScript in change_form template.